Why do we get an uncaught error, when a promise is rejected before the rejection handler is locked in?
I am trying to catch the rejection reason of an already rejected promise, but I am getting an uncaught error.
I have spent some time studying promises, but still do not understand why the error occurs.
The purpose of this question is to understand the technical (ECMAScript spec) reason for why the uncaught error happens.
Consider the following code:


const getSlowPromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('Slow promise fulfillment value');
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const getFastPromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject('Fast promise rejection reason');
    }, 200);
  });
};

const slowP = getSlowPromise();
const fastP = getFastPromise();

slowP
  .then((v) => {
    console.log(v);
    console.dir(fastP);
    return fastP;
  }, null)
  .then(
    (v) => {
      console.log(v);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log('Caught error >>> ', err);
    },
  );



In the above playground, the rejected promise is caught by the last then-handler (the rejection handler).
Inspecting the playground with DevTools will reveal that an error is thrown when fastP rejects. I am not sure why that is the case.
This is my current understanding of what is going on under the hood, in the JS engine:

When the JS engine executes the script, it synchronously creates promise objects for each chained then(onFulfilled, onRejected). Let's call the promises then-promises, with onFulfilled and onRejected then-handlers.
The onFulfilled and onRejected then-handlers are saved in each then-promise's internal [[PromiseFulfillReactions]] and [[PromiseRejectReactions]] slots. That still happens synchronously, without touching the macrotask or microtask queues
When fastP rejects, reject('Fast promise rejection reason') is added to the macrotask queue, which is passed to the call stack once empty and executed (after global execution context has finished)
When reject('Fast promise rejection reason') runs on the call stack, it will set fastP's internal [[PromiseState]] slot to rejected and the [[PromiseResult]] to 'Fast promise rejection reason'
It will then add any onRejected handler it has saved in [[PromiseRejectReactions]] to the microtask queue, which will be passed to the call stack and executed once the call stack is empty
Here is where I fall off. The then-promises we discussed previously do have handlers saved in their [[PromiseFulfillReactions]] and [[PromiseRejectReactions]] slots, as far as I understand. However, the first then-promise in the code snippet (created by the first then()) does not yet know that it should be locked in to the fastP promise, because that onFulfilled then-handler has not run yet (then-promise mirrors promise returned from the corresponding then-handler).

What am I missing? Is there a step where a connection is created between a then-promise and the returned promise from its then-handler, which only happens when the then-handler runs?

EDIT:
I understand why the rejection is caught, but not why an uncaught error first appears. I am looking for the technical explanation, to understand why it happens (see the last paragraph above).
This is the uncaught error the question relates to:
In Node.js

In DevTools in the SO playground (the snippet above)


The "slow" first .then() handler returns a Promise, that being the "fast" Promise. So the Promise mechanism does what it always does when a .then() handler returns a Promise, and processes it in the chain of (as you noted) synchronously-created .then() handlers. So the next .then() handler in the chain is reacting to the result of the "fast" Promise, which is the rejection.

@AlexanderNenashev there is, you need to inspect with DevTools, or try to run the snippet with any JS runtime, e.g. Node.js: Uncaught (in promise) Fast promise rejection reason

@pointy, Thank you, that is clear, but not the question. When the slow promise's then-handler returns the (already rejected) fast promise, the rejection reason is passed to the last onRejected then-handler. That is why the rejection is also caught. My question is related to why we get the uncaught error when the fast promise first rejects (the under-the-hood reason).

Well at the time the "fast" promise is rejected, there is no handler to deal with that, so the Promise runtime reports it as uncaught (because it is, in fact, uncaught). The status of the rejected promise remains rejected, so later when the slow Promise .then() handler (the first one) returns the "fast" Promise, it's there to be examined by the second .then() handler.

@Pointy I got that (see the steps in the OP). There must be some kind of step I am missing, as the then-handlers all create then-promises synchronously, in the global execution context (before fastP rejects). My non-technical guess, is that the then-promise is not locked in to the promise it returns, until the then-handler runs.

Ah, that is true, so the original return value of that second call to .then() is that created Promise, from the time when the .then() chain was set up. However, when the first .then() callback actually runs, it returns a Promise unrelated to the original chain, so the Promise mechanism dynamically injects it into the handling chain and that's how the second .then() is invoked.

Here's something from the Promise/A+ site: The promise resolution procedure is an abstract operation taking as input a promise and a value, which we denote as [[Resolve]](promise, x). If x is a thenable, it attempts to make promise adopt the state of x, under the assumption that x behaves at least somewhat like a promise. Otherwise, it fulfills promise with the value x.


the first then-promise in the code snippet (created by the first then()) does not yet know that it should be locked in to the fastP promise, because that onFulfilled then-handler has not run yet

And that is exactly the problem. Due to this, no promise reactions are stored on fastP - only on slowP and on the first then-promise. The promise reactions on fastP will only be created when the first then-promise is resolved with it (due to it being returned from the then handler).
So in step 5, there are no [[PromiseRejectReactions]] on fastP, and the unhandledrejection / unhandledRejection event is fired.
According to the spec, this actually happens already in step 4, where RejectPromise calls the HostPromiseRejectionTracker as fastP's [[PromiseIsHandled]] is still false. It only gets set to true when the promise is used.
Notice that as soon as slowP resolves, the then handler runs and returns fastP, and the first then-promise is "locked in" to fastP, the rejection of fastP counts as handled and the HostPromiseRejectionTracker is called from fastP.then(resolve, reject) to fire a rejectionhandled / rejectionHandled on fastP. This might further cause other unhandled rejections (on other promises, such as the first then-promise), though in your example you are handling that rejection. Your devtools may remove the error from the console (or modify it, maybe reducing it to a warning), nodejs will have already crashed the process (unless you caught the unhandledRejection) so this can no longer happen.

Deep insight and understanding of the spec, as always. Thanks a ton!

I guess we actually can think of the promise fastP and the promise returned by the first then as separate. fastP never really has a rejection handler saved in its [[PromiseRejectReactions]] slot. The first then is a promise that is settled once slowP is settled, and it just so happens to be the case that the first then promise will settle to the same fulfillment value or rejection reason as fastP (but not before the handler runs). But, in reality, they are different promises. Not sure if that matches the spec, but I guess it is a way to think about it...

Hmm, my previous comment depends on whether a promise returned by then is actually the same exact object as the promise returned from its handler, or if the two are matching but separate objects. I believe I read on MDN that Promise.resolve( promise ) returns the same exact promise object that was passed in, whereas then returns a new promise "locked in" to the promise returned by its handler. I might be wrong.

"the first then promise will settle to the same fulfillment value or rejection reason as fastP, but they are different promises." - yes, exactly. It isn't known that they'll settle with the same result until the then handler actually runs. You could even have an if (Math.random() > .5) return v; else return fastP in there, where result depends on some future value. None of this is known when .then() constructs the new promise, so it must be a separate object. (You can also check console.log(fastP !== slowP.then())). This is unrelated to what Promise.resolve does on some inputs.

Basically slowP and fastP not related to each other in any sense before you return fastP. So yes, there's no any handler to handle fastP in the first place (you attach a handler after the rejection) so that's why the error appears. Anything after
const slowP = getSlowPromise();
const fastP = getFastPromise();

doesn't matter at all, no any connection to this error. Chrome though removes this error from the console after you handle fastP with a callback. Firefox leaves the message, probably Node.js also.

Thank you, but I already understand that it does that. I am looking for the technical explanation of why it happens (see the OP steps). There must be some kind of step I am missing, as the then-handlers all create then-promises synchronously, in the global execution context (before fastP rejects). My non-technical guess, is that the then-promise is not locked in to the promise it returns, until the then-handler runs.

@Magnus I think I see what you mean by "locked-in".  And while I couldn't type it up like a language spec, I believe that your intuition is more or less correct: the new Promise returned when the first .then() runs is effectively "injected" into the dynamic processing of the chain.

Note that a .then() handler might invent a completely new Promise instance for some reason, and return that. The subsequent .then() has to handle that in a way that makes sense.

@Pointy In case curious, the OP is based on the sequentialWait in this MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#async_functions_and_execution_order. Note the warning: In sequentialWait, if promise fast rejects before promise slow is fulfilled, then an unhandled promise rejection error will be raised, regardless of whether the caller has configured a catch clause.. I just converted the example to use then() instead of await/async, as the latter is mostly sugar on top of the former.

And this is where you see the locked in concept: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value. The behavior of the returned promise (from then(), call it p) depends on the handler's execution result, following a specific set of rules.... If the handler function returns another pending promise: p is pending and becomes fulfilled/rejected with that promise's value as its value immediately after that promise becomes fulfilled/rejected.

@Magnus well that statement looks pretty much like that excerpt from Promise/A+ I posted above. When a .then() returns a Promise, an "unexpected" Promise, the mechanism "adopts" it and proceeds down the .then() chain as if that were the state of the original "incoming" Promise to the .then(). (Or something like that.) So an "alien" Promise gets adopted dynamically during the resolution chain processing.

@Pointy Yes, though I do not think there is such a thing as an "unexpected" promise. A then-promise will always match (or "adopt") whatever promise is returned from its handler (either the onFulfilled or onRejected handler, whichever applies). There is no expected or unexpected promise, as far as I know. The returned promise can be in any state. If it so happens to not be a promise, it will be implicitly converted to one via Promise.resolve(value).

@Magnus you need only const fastP = getFastPromise(); to throw this error. Everything else is unrelated and a completely different story. Your question was about this error I suppose

In lieu of support from someone who knows this part of the ECMAScript spec well, I will probably just have to accept that the connection between the promise returned in a then-handler, and the then-promise itself, only happens when the then-handler runs. I guess it is pretty obvious that it must happen that way, I was just curious how the spec explained it (without spending weeks deciphering it myself).

@AlexanderNenashev Yep, I know. The question is why it is not caught when the then-handlers are evaluated synchronously (i.e. before the fast promise actually rejects). See the OP steps.

@Magnus by "unexpected Promise" I mean a Promise that is returned by a .then() handler that has nothing to do with the original Promise chain, exactly as in your original code.

@Magnus how can the "fast" promise possibly be caught when the .then() handlers are established?!? Would you expect the Promise runtime to conduct a static analysis of the code? The .then() callbacks are just un-invoked functions until the "slow" Promise resolves.

@Pointy i'm trying to explain this also...

@Pointy I understand that it is logical that the then-promise cannot be locked in to the then-handler's returned promise before the then-handler runs. I want to understand the steps of the JS engine, i.e. how it actually works here. PS: I do not think there is any promise that is "part of the original Promise chain". Whichever promise returned from the handler will have its return value passed to the next handler, whenever that returned promise is settled.

Correct way...


const 
  getSlowPromise =_=> new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve('Slow promise fulfillment value'); }, 1000 );
    })
, getFastPromise =_=> new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
    setTimeout(() => { reject('Fast promise rejection value'); }, 200 );
    })
  ;
const slowP = getSlowPromise; // no "()", to not call or exec anything
const fastP = getFastPromise; // they are just a reference to

slowP()
.then( v =>
  {
  console.log(v);
  return fastP();  // need "()" to exec this other promise after this step
  })
.then( 
    onFulfilled => console.log( 'fastP Fulfilled' )
  , onRejected  => console.log( onRejected )
  );




Thanks for chiming in, but the whole point is to run the promises concurrently. I know how to "fix" the error, the easiest being just to use Promise.all. Alternatively, we can implement a similar functionality, where the outer promise only resolves when all the inner promises have resolved.
